# How can I ensure that my fragment's content views are available for access after committed?

Tags: android, fragment

So I have an `AsyncTask` that runs the Login procedure. Before running, I open a transaction and commit a DialogFragment to display a progress dialog to the user with a ok button in it.
I would like to make it **disabled**, only enabling it when/if the Login fails for some reason and the user can click on it and dismiss (actually popping out the dialogfragment from the stack).
I can only access the button in order to disable it in the part of the code bellow after the workaround comment.

I tried to put that code inside overrided `onAttach()` and inside `onStart()` from DialogFragment but its always returning `NullPointerException`.

Here is my code:

```
 class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        private DialogFragment  df;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            df = new DialogFragment() {
                public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this, ProgressDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
                    pd.setIndeterminate(true);
                    pd.setCancelable(false);
                    pd.setMessage(getString(R.string.login_message));
                    pd.setTitle(getString(R.string.login_title));
                    pd.setButton(ProgressDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                        }
                    });
                    return pd;
                };
            };
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(df, "LOGIN_DLG_FRAG").commit();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                        // WORKAROUND
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ((ProgressDialog)df.getDialog()).getButton(ProgressDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
                }
            });
                         ...
      }
     }
```

I know the `FragmentTransaction.commit()` schedule the operations, so I would like to know how can access the view components of the fragment the correct way.

Thanks in advance.